# how can i remove an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```js
function insertNumber(){
    let numberValue
    let body = document.body
    let div  = document.createElement('div')
    if (document.getElementById('intInput').value === ''){
            div.setAttribute('id', 'error')
            div.textContent = 'error'
            body.insertBefore(div, body.childNodes[0])
    } else{
        numberValue = document.getElementById('intInput').value
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = numberValue
    }
```

how can i remove `div` variabale When `else` is realized

Comment: You never added it, so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: Are you asking how you can remove the element that was added by a previous call?

Comment: There is a possibility for multiple elements with the same `error` id...

Comment: I recommend that instead of adding and removing elements, you put the element in the static HTML. Then use CSS to show and hide it as necessary.

Comment: @Barmar yes i meant that

Comment: and How can I do this with css? @Barmar

Comment: `div.style.display = "none";` to hide, `div.style.display = "block";` to show. Or toggle a class that has `display: none;` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the element already exists. If it does, you can reuse it in the `if`, and remove it in the `else`.

```js
function insertNumber() {
  let numberValue;
  let body = document.body;
  let div = document.getElementById("error");
  if (document.getElementById('intInput').value === '') {
    if (!div) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute('id', 'error');
      body.insertBefore(div, body.childNodes[0]);
    }
    div.textContent = 'error'
  } else {
    numberValue = document.getElementById('intInput').value
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = numberValue
    if (div) {
      div.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it worth having that code in a snippet? @barmar

Comment: @Andy Sometimes when I use the snippet editor I just don't feel like removing the wrapper after inserting. I don't think it's important either way.

Comment: Fair enough. It wasn't a complaint, just an observation.

Comment: Understood, and my answer was just an explanation, not a refutation. :)